# use flash as proxy for e4x?

Tags: flash, proxy, e4x

I really like processing XML with e4x, any other method I just get confused and can't seem to get it to work. So I was thinking about maybe making a proxy in flash to use to process xml with e4x (I would use this for JavaScript and maybe PHP if I could figure out a way). Basically passing it an xml object and an e4x expression and returning the results. Before I even start to think about how I could make this possible I wanted to know if this is a terrible idea? Is this a waste of time or could this be good?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds very inefficient. Technically sounds doable (through ExternalInterface) but I'd search for E4X libraries for JS or PHP.

Or take a look to XPath if you only want to learn one way of interacting with XMLs in all 3 platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at Aptana Jaxer, it is a server side JavaScript server which uses headless Firefox. Firefox supports e4x in JavaScript natively so everything should work just fine.